# Python combination of 2 lists (1 repeat, 1 non-repeat)

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations, product, python-itertools

What is the best way to find all of the combinations of 2 lists where the values in 1 list can repeat and in the other list they cannot repeat?  Right now, I can get all of the combinations of the repeating list as in:

```
import itertools
rep = ['A','B','C', 'D']
norep = ['1','2','3','4']
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(rep,4):
    print i
```

I can get all of the combinations of the non-repeating list:

```
for i in itertool.combinations(norep,4):
    print i
```

and I can get the combinations of the two lists as if they are both non-repeating:

```
for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4):
    print [(norep[j] if i else rep[j]) for j, i in enumerate(i)]
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the combinations of the repeating and the non repeating list.  I'd also like to add in the combinations including null values, e.g.['A','1',Null].

Comment: Should each combination draw a fixed number `n` values from the first list and `m` from the second, with and without repetition respectively? Or do you want to draw a `n` values from a combined pool, allowing repetitions of elements from one list, but not from the other?

Comment: Note: Your "combinations of the two lists as if they are both non-repeating" code doesn't work. It'll never draw the first 2 elements from both lists.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for checking that. I didn't notice my combinations of the two lists didn't yield all of the combinations.  In your 1st post, I want the latter behavior.  I would like to specify the amount of values in a combination,e.g. n=4 gives [A,B,1,2],etc or n=5 gives [A,C,1,3,null], etc.

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple `None`s? (And would you prefer a tuple with `None`s in it, or just a shorter tuple?)

Comment: @user2357112 I want to allow multiple 'None's and would like them to be in the tuple.  I thought about adding them in 'rep' and 'norep' but wasn't sure if that would give the desired behavior.

Comment: @user2357112  I've come up with what I think is a solution.  Could you take a look at it for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I got. Pretty close to yours:

```
from itertools import chain
from itertools import combinations
# Huge name!
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
from itertools import starmap
from itertools import product

from operator import add

def _weird_combinations(rep, no_rep, n_from_rep, n_from_norep):
    return starmap(add, product(cwr(rep, n_from_rep),
                                combinations(no_rep, n_from_norep)))

def weird_combinations(rep, no_rep, n):
    rep, no_rep = list(rep), list(no_rep)

    # Allow Nones in the output to represent drawing less than n elements.
    # If either input has None in it, this will be confusing.
    rep.append(None)

    # We can't draw more elements from no_rep than it has.
    # However, we can draw as many from rep as we want.
    least_from_rep = max(0, n-len(no_rep))
    return chain.from_iterable(
            _weird_combinations(rep, no_rep, n_from_rep, n-n_from_rep)
            for n_from_rep in xrange(least_from_rep, n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a solution, but please correct me if this wrong.  I would also love to see if there are any more elegant solutions.

First, I came up with the total number of combinations.  All combinations without replacement are equal to n!/r!(n-r)! and with replacement are equal to (m+s-1)!/s!(m-1)! where m and n are number of items to choose from and r and s are the number of items you actually choose.  Because I know the total items I want in each combination (lets call it cap), I find the number of combinations for 0 of the no replacement type (n=0) and for "cap" of the replacement type (m=3) and multiply those numbers together.  Then, add to that the number of combinations for 1 of the no replacement type (n=1) multiplied by combinations "cap-1" of the replacement type (m=2). Do this until you have finally added combinations for "cap" of the no replacement type (n=3) multiplied by 0 of the replacement type (m=0) (thanks @André Nicolas).  The code for number of combinations is below.

```
import itertools
from math import factorial as fact
norep = ['A','B','C']
rep = ['1','2','3']

cap = 3     #length of combinations, e.g. cap=3, combo1=123,combo2=A12,etc
combos = 0

for i in range(cap+1):
    combnorep = fact(len(norep))/(fact(cap-i)*fact(len(norep)-(cap-i)))
    combrep = fact(len(rep)+i-1)/(fact(i)*fact(len(rep)-1))
    combos = combos + combnorep*combrep
print combos
```

For this example, the number of combos is 38.  Next, I wanted to print all of the combinations.  To do this, I determined the combinations for all replacements, all no replacements, and any combination of the two,e.g. n=0,m=3;n=1,m=2;etc.  This is what I came up with:

```
for i in range(cap+1):
    norepcomb = [j for j in itertools.combinations(norep,i)]
    repcomb = [k for k in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(rep,cap-i)]
    for l in itertools.product(norepcomb,repcomb):
        print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
```

To include `none`, I would just include `none` in my list for with replacement combinations.  I'd like any feedback on this especially if there is a better solution or if this doesn't work like I think it does.  Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was doing before I got bored and played some video games instead. You don't need some of those list comprehensions, and my code produced a different output format. I think I still have the tab with my work open.